# How do stars look like from space?

Tags: astronomy, space, stars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optical explanation of images of stars?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/optical-explanation-of-images-of-stars)
>   [What are these rays that appear in photograph of sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35935/what-are-these-rays-that-appear-in-photograph-of-sun)

I thought stars should look round shaped (similar to a sphere, or oblate spheroid) without extra tails nor should they twinkle as they were only caused by atmospheric distortion when seen from Earth. However I searched the web for some justification photos and I didn't find any. I found [this photo from NASA which I expect was taken from space, that shows extra tails on the star](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg)[image]

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg

Do you have any explanation?