# How can light appear to spread in mainly a few rays (e.g: 2,4)?

Tags: visible-light

I think it's easier to explain the question with some images.

[image]
Here you can see a six-rayed one:
[image]

I cannot post more than 2 links, so:

www.i.stack.imgur.com/23YLa.jpg

www.i.stack.imgur.com/4WqEU.jpg

Why does it spread in such rays only? How does it happen?

I guess many of you have seen this before. Maybe the answer is quite simple but I don't know it and it did not seem to me it has been asked already.

Comment: This is not a property of light in itself (although diffraction plays a major role here), but of the optics (meaning the apparatus) that was used to create the image. See this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/optical-explanation-of-images-of-stars and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike

Answer (score 1):

This is just an effect of the optics used to take the images. The size of the aperture causes the light to be bend: [Wikipedia: Airy Disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk).
Now, as the aperture of most lenses is not circular, the edges cause some visible rays in the image, as is depicted [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beugungsscheibchen#/media/File:Twod_fourier_1.png). The left column shows an assumed shape of the aperture and the right column the resulting image of a point-like source of light.

Especially in telescopes using mirrors, this effect is also caused by the mechanics holding the mirrors in place: [Wikipedia: Diffration Spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike)

In photography this effect is often used for artistic reasons. If you own a good camera (DSLR or similar), try taking pictures of the same small light source with different aperture settings: The smaller the aperture, the more visible this effect is.