# What aberration causes the common "cross pattern" in astronomy images?

Tags: optics, astronomy, geometric-optics, imaging

I am trying to understand the origin of the plus/cross-sign aberrations commonly seen for point sources in astronomical images, even ones created with professional-grade, high-quality optics. The one in the image below clearly has some chromatic dependence but its pattern tells me it's not purely chromatic aberration. I can't understand what physical cause gives rise to this particular pattern so commonly.

Thanks.

[image: The aberration I seek to understand]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optical explanation of images of stars?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/optical-explanation-of-images-of-stars), and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

These are known as [diffraction spikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike). They are typically caused by diffraction on the struts that hold the secondary mirror in front of the primary:

[image]

<sup>[Image source: Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Newtonianscope-inside.JPG)</sup>

In your picture, the chromatic effect appears because scale of the diffraction pattern changes with the wavelength, so with a white-light source you get the fringes of different colors in different places, producing the colorful mix that you observe.

For more details, see the Wikipedia link above.

Comment: Appreciated, this is it exactly. It also makes sense with our thought experiment, which was that squinting seems to cause this too along the axis of eyelashes --- I suggested it was diffraction however it didn't occur to me to consider the telescope support structures.